# Wait for internet connection to load external script

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm trying to load an external script in a Cordova app html, but I'm facing some issues. The app is offline, but some specific online functions depend on this script.

Using `<script src="https://sitename.com/something.js"></script>` to load the script file works as intended if the device is online, but if the device is offline, the app shows an `The connection to the server was unsucessful error` and closes.

Using `<script src="https://sitename.com/something.js" async defer></script>` works when the device is offline, but since the script didn't load, if the device goes online while the app is in foreground and trigger something that rely on this script, the app shows an error too.

I want to load the `something.js` once when the device is online and connection is properly working. How can I do this? There's a way to load scripts via JavaScript?

Comment: I don't have an answer at the top of my head, but reading http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml the information on that page looks interesting. You can wrap this around logic that detects if the file has been loaded or not, if not you can use the function in that article.

I have not tested his/her code.

Comment: You could test the connection status with a plugin like this: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information. It emits an event on connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script in intervals to check the network status : 
[OnlineJS](http://pixelscommander.com/polygon/onlinejs/)

By Checking the internet access whenever the device goes online it trigger an event .

In that event function refresh the page .

when you refresh the page script tags will be reloaded

```
Assign window.onLineHandler or window.offLineHandler functions to handle status changes.
```